# Haskell: insert or append value inside associative list

Tags: dictionary, haskell

I have an associative list with dynamic size of type Map k [v] like this

```
myList = fromList [(10,[11,12]),(20,[21,22]),(12,[10,11])]
```

in which I want to insert values depending on the key like so

```
-- insert value 13 in tuple (10,[11,12]) ==> (10,[11,12,13])
```

I'm getting more familiar with manipulation list but I'm really stack her. When I use insert like this :

```
--insert value 11 where key equals to 12
insert 12 [11] (fromList [(10,[11,12]),(11,[10,12]),(12,[10])]) == fromList [(10,[11,12]),(11,[10,12]),(12,[11])]
```

It does not produce [10,11] but rather replace [10] by [11].

And if my list is empty. `myList = fromList Map.empty`and I want to insert a tuple (10,11) to my list. I want to expect this behavior as a result

```
myList = insert 10 11 Map.empty ==> [(10,[11]),(11,[10]))]
```

Any indications, ideas or hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`insertWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:insertWith) instead:

```
Prelude Data.Map> let myList = fromList [(10,[11,12]),(11,[10,12]),(12,[10])]
Prelude Data.Map> insertWith (++) 12 [11] myList
fromList [(10,[11,12]),(11,[10,12]),(12,[11,10])]
```

As for your second requirement, you can try this:

```
import Prelude hiding (null)
import Data.Map

insertEmpty :: Int -> Int -> Map Int [Int] -> Map Int [Int]
insertEmpty x y hmap

    -- If map is empty, return the paired tuples
    | null hmap = pairs

    -- If the map is the same as pairs, return it unchanged
    | hmap == pairs = hmap

    -- Otherwise insert into map
    | otherwise = insertWith (++) x [y] hmap

    where pairs = fromList [(x, [y]), (y, [x])]
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> let myList = fromList [(11,[12]),(12,[11])]
*Main> insertEmpty 11 12 myList
fromList [(11,[12]),(12,[11])]
*Main> let myList = fromList []
*Main> insertEmpty 11 12 myList
fromList [(11,[12]),(12,[11])]
*Main> let myList = fromList [(10,[11,12]),(11,[10,12]),(12,[10])]
*Main> insertEmpty 11 12 myList
fromList [(10,[11,12]),(11,[12,10,12]),(12,[10])]
```

Comment: I have a type error with this function. Couldn't match  expected type Map Int [Int] with actual type [(Int,[Int])] after loading my file.hs. Yes I'll edit my question after getting it to work.

Comment: @DavidEdgar hmm, are you calling it like above? It should compile fine.

Comment: I have put every thing from import to were in one file.hs and when I do :l error .

Comment: @DavidEdgar Ah sorry my bad, was calling `fromList` twice. Try it now. Their might be some logic inaccuracies but the overall idea is fine.

Comment: I appreciate your help, it works fine now as expected.